# how to use active resource for multiple database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

this is my scenario

User registering in a site ,after successful registration activation link sent to the user to the specified mail  , while clicking the link default data required to use the main site will be generated in the respective table of that database.

registration information is in different database , and default data should be added in different database.

how to work on this issue?

Is that possible to call rake db:migrate multiple times every time user register in the site

Or

we can use activeresource to establish the connection to that database and create entry for the table

can any one give solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'me giving you a -1 for not taking the time to research and understand what `rake db:migrate` does because this a fairly trivial piece of knowledge you need when working with Rails. What `rake db:migrate` does is modify your database (create, drop, change tables, etc), so I don't see how relevant it would be to run every time a user registers on your site.

Second, ActiveResource is used not to access a different database. What it does is:

> Active Resource (ARes) connects business objects and Representational State Transfer (REST) web services. It implements object-relational mapping for REST web services to provide transparent proxying capabilities between a client (ActiveResource) and a RESTful service (which is provided by Simply RESTful routing in ActionController::Resources).

To connect to a different database, simply have an entry in your database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: dev_database
  username: user
  password: password

different_database:
  adapter: mysql
  database: shared_database
  username: user
  password: password
```

Then, inside the model you want to connect to a different database you do

```
establish_connection :different_database
```